# Creating a custom binary pattern from a given number

Tags: algorithms

Given n, I have a binary pattern to be generated like this in a part of my application:

```
n = 0

0 -> 0

n = 1

0 -> 0
1 -> 1

n = 2

0 -> 00
1 -> 01
2 -> 10
3 -> 11

n = 3

0 -> 000
1 -> 001
2 -> 010
3 -> 100
4 -> 011
5 -> 101
6 -> 110
7 -> 111

n = 4

0 -> 0000
1 -> 0001
2 -> 0010
3 -> 0100
4 -> 1000
5 -> 0011
6 -> 0101
7 -> 1001
8 -> 0110
9 -> 1010
10 -> 1100
11 -> 0111
12 -> 1011
13 -> 1101
14 -> 1110
15 -> 1111

n = 5

0 -> 00000
1 -> 00001
2 -> 00010
3 -> 00100
4 -> 01000
5 -> 10000
6 -> 00011
7 -> 00101
8 -> 01001
9 -> 10001
10 -> 00110
11 -> 01010
12 -> 10010
13 -> 01100
14 -> 10100
15 -> 11000
16 -> 00111
17 -> 01011
18 -> 10011
19 -> 01101
20 -> 10101
21 -> 11001
22 -> 01110
23 -> 10110
24 -> 11010
25 -> 11100
26 -> 01111
27 -> 10111
28 -> 11011
29 -> 11101
30 -> 11110
31 -> 11111
```

I'll try to explain this algorithm the best way I can:

The algorithm has loops. In each loop, an extra bit is flipped. Then combinations are to be made out of it.

So in the first loop, no bits are 1s.

In the second loop, only one bit is 1. We need to first go through all possible combinations, in such an order that the leftmost bits are lit only after all combinations for the rightmost bits are over.

Similarly keep proceeding to further loops.

I'm not sure how to write an efficient code for it. One thing I could think of is like a DP solution to this problem. But could there be a more elegant, something like a mathematical solution, where I could put in 'n' and get the binary pattern equivalent? Would something like this even be possible?

I'd ideally like to get the equivalent binary for a number. Say I give n=5 and number = 10, then I need 00110.

Comment: Given $n$ you would like to create all possible numbers or only a given $x$?

Comment: As per your explanation, for $n=4$, why does $1001$ go before $0110$?

Comment: I think they are iterating over the number of $1$'s in the first n digits, $n$ decreasing (that is, $1001$ is before $0110$ because both have two $1$'s, but $1001$ has only one $1$ in the first three digits as opposed to $1001$ having two)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ekin said it right

Comment: @cgss My use case would be that if I had a number, say 10, and n, say 5, I need to get 00110, in the least computationally complex way possible. That is my ideal scenario.

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar I would suggest to edit the question to clarify this information.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, but one that comes first to my mind:

1. Calculate $a_m=\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}$ for all $0\leq m\leq n$. You can do this faster by using identities like ${m\choose k}+{m\choose k+1}={m+1\choose k+1}$. Basically, you are going through the Pascal triangle and adding up while calculating. This is the part that could get too big numbers, or too much running time, but if you have small $n$'s and many numbers you want to sample at once, this might not be too bad.
2. Let $x$ be the number you want to sample. You can easily find the number $m$ of $1$'s in your representation: It is the smallest $m$ such that $a_m\geq x$. If $m=0$, we are done, so assume this is not the case.

Now for clarity, I define $L$ to be "the lower threshold". This is a nice number that will be not more than $x$ throughout. Typically, it will be the last number that has $l$ many $1$'s in the first $l'$ many digits for some $l,l'$.Initially, $L=a_{m-1}$; because we picked $m$ to be maximal, this is certainly a lower bound for $x$.

3. Now you want to find out whether the last digit is $1$ or not. To this end, we observe that the first $n-1\choose m-1$ among numbers from $L$ on have to end with 1, so if $x-L\leq {n-1\choose m-1}$, the last digit will be 1, else it will be 0. If it is 0, we update our lower bound $L:=L+{n-1\choose m-1}$.
4. You can fill the other digits in a similar fashion, where you replace $m$ with the number of $1$'s left, and each time you get a 0, you have to update your $L$ accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Is it possible to tweak it in a way I can get the binary pattern equivalent for a particular number? For instance, for n=5 and number = 10, I get 00110, without having to generate the entire patten?

Comment: @Ekin I was thinking something along the same lines. I think you can be a bit more efficient in step 3 by computing the number of 1's in the end via a binary search.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.